# Error while creating and instance of IE

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, firewatir

Hi all while I try to create an instance of IE I am facing the following error
my system configurations
Windows 7,64 bit

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Watir::IE
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'watir'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> ie=Watir::IE.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Watir::IE
    from (irb):3
    from D:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:630
irb(main):004:0>
```

Comment: try `ie = Watir::Browser.new`?

Comment: I tried with above command still not working

Answer (score 0):

To launch a browser in watir, you shoul use :

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
# or :ff or :chrome or :opera ...
```

Note that for Internet explorer, you should download IEDriverServer.exe and add it to your path.